# c# Unique variable Name

Tags: c#, variables, unique

Hi there I have a bit of a noob question about creating unique variable names in C#. 
I would like to make an ArrayList of Enemy objects and I want to call each enemy "enemy[1]"
I would like to make a for loop and I would like to use the value of "i" to add on to the end of the word enemy.
so for instance:

```
forloop
{
Enemy enemy1 = new Enemy(actual parameters of the enemy class)
Enemy enemy2 = new Enemy();
Enemy enemy3 = new Enemy();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?  There's got to be a better way to do what you want?  What's wrong with a `List<Enemy>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables cannot be dynamically named as you desire, but by using arrays or lists (but please don't use *ArrayLists*, more below!), you can access via indexes.

Create a `List<Enemy>` (`List<T>` is found in System.Collections.Generic)

```
var enemies = new List<Enemy>();
enemies.Add(new Enemy()); // add as many as you need
```

Or if the collection does not need to be dynamically sized, you could use a simple array, of which there are several legal syntaxes for creation.

```
Enemy[] enemies = { new Enemy(), new Enemy(), new Enemy() };
```

Then you can write your loop and access via the *index*

```
// enemies.Count if using List<Enemy>
// enemies.Length if using Enemy[] array
for (int index = 0; index < enemies.Count; index++) 
{
    enemies[index].FireWeapon();
}
```

Or write a foreach loop

```
foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
{
    enemy.FireWeapon();
}
```

---

Your notion about using an `ArrayList` is outdated as of C# 2.0+ (the current release on the market is C# 4.0), or Visual Studio 2005 (2010 is the current market version). It is preferrable to use the strongly typed generic collections found in the aforementioned System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Comment: Cool thanks for the advice will use the list method you described above.

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor to your enemy class

```
public class Enemy
{
    public Enemy(string name, int score)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Score = score;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Fill enemy with

```
Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[10];
for (int i = 0; i < enemy.Length; i++) {
    enemy[i] = new Enemy("Foe #" + i, 100);
}
```

or with

```
List<Enemy> enemy = new List<Enemy>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    enemy.Add(new Enemy("Foe #" + i, 100));
}
```

You can also use an object initializer instead of consturctor parameters

```
var e = new Enemy{ Name = "X", Score = 100 };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<Enemy> listOfYourEnemy = new List<Enemy>();
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     listOfYourEnemy.Add(new Enemy() {unqName= string.Format("enemy{0}", i)}); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy> { 
    new Enemy(), 
    new Enemy(), 
    new Enemy() };
```

or even

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();
for (int i = 0; i < someNumberOfEnemiesDefinedElsewhere; i++)
{
    enemies.Add( new Enemy( "Enemy" + i ) );
}
```

otherwise, we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            enemies.Add(new Enemy() { Parameters... });
        }

        // Access to objects by index
        Enemy enemy2 = enemies[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to name them or just create *n* enemy variables?

To create *n* variables use an array w/in your for loop:

```
EnemyArray[*n*]
for(int i =0; i< *n*; i++)
{
  EnemyArray[i] = new Enemy()
}
```

Now you can get the 1st Enemy like this

```
Enemy myEnemy = EnemyArray[0]
```

The second like this

```
 Enemy myEnemiesEnemy = EnemyArray[1]
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you're asking.  If you really want to reference the objects by those names you could put them in a dictionary.

```
var enemies = new Dictionary<string, Enemy>();
for (int i = 0; i < ??? ; i++)
{
    enemies["enemy"+i.ToString()] = new Enemy(...);
}
```

Then you can reference them like this:

```
enemies["enemy1"].FireWeapon();
```